# With OnKeyListener, what is the difference between return true and false?

Tags: android

What is the different between return `true` and `false` with `OnKeyListener`?

I look at the android official document [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html" ")!.

However, I still dont get to truly understand it. Can anyone explain it to me more explicit on how `OnKeyListener` reach to those two returns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The event will continue to *bubble up* the container chain if you return `false`

> Returns True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

Because, if you think about it, what we do is to necessarily nest `view`s inside one another:

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:onClick="layoutClicked" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:onClick="myButtonClicked" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Imagine a click on the button, if you donT return `true`, `layoutClicked` will also fire after the `myButtonClicked` handler.

I think there is more explanation [in this article](http://codetheory.in/understanding-android-input-touch-events/)

Comment: Why we need to return false on touch listener like button for example? Dont we want that listener to handle the event by itself every time.

Comment: Can you give me one good example when I need to return false for the listener?

Comment: 1/ you donT HAVE TO return false. but for simple cases, once the code in the button handler is executed, you are done with the event.

Comment: 2/ Imagine that you want your LinearLayout to change color when the layout itself or any of the elements within this container is clicked.